# Tesseract "Failed loading language..." on windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, ocr, tesseract

Windows 7, Tesseract 3.02

All I'm trying to do is run "tesseract img.jpg img" from cmd.exe.

I'm running it from my C:\...\Tesseract-OCR directory.

But I get the error:

> Error opening data file
>   C:\...\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata/tessdata/eng.traineddata
>
> Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to
>   the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
>
> Failed loading language 'eng'
>
> Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
>
> Could not initialize tesseract.

How can I fix this?

This problem has been brought up many times it seems (around the web), but no answers I've come across have done me any good.

I've tried doing "set TESSDATA_PREFIX=C:\...\Tesseract-OCR" but nothing changes.

Does it have to do with the reversal of the backslashes|forward slashes in the path?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled.... works fine now :B

Correct Output:

> Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica